# Powershell script to replace text in an array of files. Overwriting the whole file. What am I doing wrong?

Tags: windows, powershell, text, replace

I'm trying to use this script to replace text in a few files. It keeps replacing the content of the entire file though when I test it on the directory I have here on my PC. What am I missing? I'm very new at this...

```
$CTPath = "C:\path1"
$ECTPath = "C:\path2"
$FileExistCT = Test-Path $CTPath
$FileExistECT = Test-Path $ECTPath

If ($FileExistCT -eq $True)
{
    $filenames = @("Filepath1.vxm", "Filepath2.vxm", "Filepath3.vxm")
    foreach ($file in $filenames){
    $outputfile="$file" + ".out"

    Get-Content $file | Foreach-object
{
    $_ -replace "DISTS2D = 636.5", "DISTS2D = 642.9" `
} | Set-Content $outputfile
}
}
ElseIf ($FileExistECT -eq $True)
{
    $filenames = @("Filepath1.vxm", "Filepath2.vxm", "Filepath3.vxm", "Filepath4.vxm", "Filepath5.vxm", "Filepath6.vxm", "FilePath7.vxm")
    foreach ($file in $filenames){
    $outputfile="$file" + ".out"

Get-Content $file | Foreach
{
     $_ -replace "DISTS2D = 636.5", "DISTS2D = 642.9" `
} | Set-Content $outputfile
}
}
Else {Write-Host "VXM Files Not Found. Verify file path and try again."}
```

I'm probably going about this in a very roundabout way as well.. but I need to get this working. The VXM files are read just as any old text file. When I use this script, it overwrites the entire file with:

$_ -replace "DISTS2D = 636.5", "DISTS2D = 642.9" `

But when I test it using a basic replacement function it works without any issues.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of this structure:

```
Get-Content $file | Foreach-object {
    $_ -replace "DISTS2D = 636.5", "DISTS2D = 642.9" `
} | Set-Content $outputfile
```

I'd suggest this:

```
$search = [regex]::Escape("DISTS2D = 636.5")    
(Get-Content $file) -replace $search, "DISTS2D = 642.9" | Set-Content $outputfile
```

The escaped regex is not particularly needed because you only have one special character (the dot) but it will ensure no false positive matches.

<s>In your original code you are regex updating each line of the input file and sending it to  Set-Content. Since Set-Content doesn't append by default it should only contain the last line of the input file. You could replace it with `Out-File -Append` but if you just use the `-replace` operator against the whole input file contents it won't be an issue to stick with `Set-Content`.</s>

I'm not sure why you are getting a single line of text in your output file. My guess since you were getting a single line of text that Set-Content was only putting the last item in the pipeline but I wasn't sure why you were getting your line of code as the content of the file instead of the updated text. After @msorens questioned my conclusion in the comments I tried your code with some VMX files and it actually worked for me so I'm not sure why you had an issue.

I modified this slightly.

```
foreach ($file in $files){
    $outputfile = $file.FullName + ".out"
    Get-Content $file | Foreach-object {
        $_ -replace 'virtualHW.version = "7"', 'virtualHW.version = "andy"' `
    } | Set-Content $outputfile
}
```

Comment: It works! Thanks a lot. I've just started using powershell this week and love it so far.

Comment: I was skeptical of your reasoning, Andy, so I double-checked with a quick test to confirm my thinking. The fact that Set-Content does not append by default is irrelevant; simply put _Set-Content understands pipeline input_ so it will correctly process all lines fed to it here. That said, my test suggests that the original code in the question works fine; so there is something else going on that Zephon13 has not yet isolated.

Comment: @msorens Fair enough. You're right about Set-Content writing all input from the pipeline. Exemplified `1..10 | sc C:\a.txt ; gc C:\a.txt`. I processed the OP's code with my brain, rather than a PowerShell instance hehe.